# which files were automatically merged in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

When mercurial reports that it has merged files, how do I get the list of those automatically merged files? Is there a way to see this?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there are plenty.  Mercurial doesn't commit that merge for you, so you can see what was modified using just:

```
hg status
```

If you want more detail you can use

```
hg resolve --list
```